# Calling specific variable VBA Rest API

Tags: vba, excel

I am struggling to understand how I can call a specific variable and organize it in an excel worksheet.

I need to get the buy, sell and vol from this url https://api.blinktrade.com/api/v1/BRL/ticker?crypto_currency=BTC but I am not able to find out how to separate it.

I am using this code to call the data

```
Public Sub btcteste()

'Dim xmlhttp As Object

Dim xmlhttp As New MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60

Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP")

Dim myurl As String

myurl = "https://api.blinktrade.com/api/v1/BRL/ticker?crypto_currency=BTC"
xmlhttp.Open "GET", myurl, False
xmlhttp.send
MsgBox (xmlhttp.responseText)

End Sub
```

And it is working but how can I separate the variables and paste it in single cells?

Thanks

Comment: When your question is about getting nodes from an XML document using VBA, many examples can be found on the internet. For StackOverflow this question is too broad.

Comment: @HenkvanBoeijen, that data is JSON, not XML, formatted

Comment: "but I am not willing to find out how to separate it" - That's the first time I have seen a question where the poster admits they don't want to do the research! ;)  (Hopefully it was just a poor choice of wording and wasn't intended to mean what I read it as. :D)

Comment: @YowE3K, i just corrected the translation. i think that the phrase should be "not able" or "can not" ( i chose "not able")

Answer (score 1):

```
Public Sub btcteste()

    Dim xmlhttp As Object

    'Dim xmlhttp As New MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60

    Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP")

    Dim myurl As String

    myurl = "https://api.blinktrade.com/api/v1/BRL/ticker?crypto_currency=BTC"
    xmlhttp.Open "GET", myurl, False
    xmlhttp.send

    Dim data As Variant
    data = xmlhttp.responseText

    Debug.Print data

    ' example data
    ' {"high": 13400.0, "vol": 616.03500983, "buy": 12830.59, "last": 12899.78, "low": 11800.0, "pair": "BTCBRL", "sell": 12899.78, "vol_brl": 7808332.67293126}

    ' split at comma (,) , and then split at colon (:)

    data = Split(data, ",")    ' convert to array

    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("b2:b4") = Application.Transpose(Array("buy", "sell", "vol"))

    ' buy, sell and vol
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("c2") = Split(data(2), ":")(1)  ' buy
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("c3") = Split(data(6), ":")(1)  ' sell
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("c4") = Split(data(1), ":")(1)  ' vol

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much it worked perfectly!

Do you recommend a library to understand all the commands you wrote?

Comment: which part do you need to know about?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.

```
Public Sub btcteste()

    Dim xmlhttp As Object

    'Dim xmlhttp As New MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60

    Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP")

    Dim myurl As String
    Dim strText As String
    Dim vSplit As Variant, v As Variant
    Dim vR() As Variant
    Dim n As Integer

    myurl = "https://api.blinktrade.com/api/v1/BRL/ticker?crypto_currency=BTC"
    xmlhttp.Open "GET", myurl, False
    xmlhttp.send
    'MsgBox (xmlhttp.responseText)
    strText = xmlhttp.responseText
    strText = Replace(strText, "}", "")
    strText = Replace(strText, "{", "")
    strText = Replace(strText, Chr(34), "")
    vSplit = Split(strText, ",")
    For Each v In vSplit
        n = n + 1
        ReDim Preserve vR(1 To 2, 1 To n)
        vR(1, n) = Trim(Split(v, ":")(0))
        vR(2, n) = Trim(Split(v, ":")(1))
    Next v
    Range("a1").Resize(n, 2) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(vR) '<~~ this is vertical
    'Range("a1").Resize(2, n) = vR  '<~~ this is horisontal
End Sub
```